# Create C# Project Templates in Visual Studio 2022 (.NET6)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, vsix, project-template, vsixmanifest

I have `VS 2022` with dotnet 6. I want to create custom project templates.

1. How do I package it, so that my peers can just use it in their machine ?
   (I tried VSIX but I think it does not support dotnet 6 yet)
2. Also, I want to use custom variables. e.g. if I create a project with name `XYZ`,[image] the controller name should be 'XYZController'. and I want to use this variable value across multiple places within the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comprehensive [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) for creating a custom template. Here is the steps for packageing:

> A custom template is packed with the `dotnet` pack command and a
> `.csproj` file. Alternatively, NuGet can be used with the `nuget` pack
> command along with a `.nuspec` file. However, NuGet requires the .NET
> Framework on Windows and Mono on Linux and macOS.

The `.csproj` file is slightly different from a traditional code-project `.csproj` file. Note the following settings:

1. The  setting is added and set to Template.
2. The  setting is added and set to a valid NuGet
   version number.
3. The  setting is added and set to a unique identifier.
   This identifier is used to uninstall the template pack and is used
   by NuGet feeds to register your template pack.
4. Generic metadata settings should be set: , ,
   , and .
5. The  setting must be set, even though the binary
   produced by the template process isn't used. In the example below
   it's set to netstandard2.0.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) for a working example.